# How to 'merge' a XAML file and its code-behind with Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, code-behind

I have a template defined in a XAML file named 'MyTemplate.xaml'. This template is using a code-behind file named 'MyTemplate.cs'.

**Mytemplate.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Project.Templates.MyTemplate">
    <DataTemplate ... />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MyTemplate.cs**:

```
namespace Project.Templates
{
    public partial class MyTemplate : ResourceDictionary
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, these two files are side by side. What I would like to do is to put these two files together, just like with a Control and its code-behind.

What I have: [image]

What I would like to have: [image]

What is the best way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that... I mean what is your aim once you have this 'merged' file?

Comment: It's just clearer in the Solution Explorer. It allows me to see which template file is associated with which template code-behind. Don't you find it useful for Controls?

Comment: In that case, please explain how to add an event handler to a template without using code-behind...

Comment: I've added a suggestion answer.

Comment: @Sheridan, "code-behind pages are old school", really? Just because you use the MVVM pattern doesn't mean that you can't use code-behind; there are still many cases where code-behind is the right place to do something, especially if it's purely UI-related.

Comment: @MorganM. I've answered your question regarding responding to an event without code-behind, hope it helps :)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, WPF is all about binding whether you use MVVM or not. What I meant was that in WinForms, you *had* to use the code behind, whereas WPF does not follow this pattern. I don't believe that I said that someone can't use the code behind, did I?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to edit the .csproj file. Find the `<Compile>` element for MyTemplate.cs, and add a `<DependentUpon>` element under it:

```
<Compile Include="MyTemplate.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyTemplate.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

See this blog post: [make a project item a child item of another](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/05/visual-studio-trick-make-a-project-item-a-child-item-of-another/)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to say to Visual to open the .cs file instead of the XAML file when I select 'View code' after a right click on my template?

Comment: @MorganM., for me it opens the code-behind... Perhaps the file has to be named MyTemplate.xaml.cs

Comment: Yes, this works with '.xaml.cs' instead of '.cs'. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, the dependency is created automatically if the code-behind file has the same name than the XAML file + the .xaml suffix before the .cs extension.

Comment: It might help to point out that the `Include` value would be a relative path to the file like `Views\Controls\MyTemplate.xaml.cs`, whereas the `DependentUpon` value will just be the file name, in this case `MyTemplate.xaml`.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris no idea. I never used VS for Mac

Comment: I finally saw it

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan that actually made it work.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your initial question, but to this:

> In that case, please explain how to add an event handler to a template without using code-behind

You can do this with a ViewModel and an ICommand class.

First you need to create your ViewModel class, make this public and non static with a parameter-less constructor.

Then create another class which implements the ICommand interface:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //this is what happens when you respond to the event
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Add an instance of your command class to your ViewModel class, make this private and expose it through a read-only property:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand _command = new Command();

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }
}
```

Add your ViewModel as a static resource, in your App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <wpfApplication1:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Set your DataContext of your XAML file to your ViewModel:

```
<Window DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
```

Now respond to your event by binding to the Command class:

```
<Button Click="{Binding Command}"></Button>
```

Boom, no code-behind. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is indeed not an answer to my question but I didn't know this way of implementing event handlers without code-behind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to:

- Add/Create a new XAML file/item
- Copy and paste the old .xaml and xaml.cs content to the new equivalent files
- delete the separate files
- rename the new file

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is:

1. Exclude unlinked files from project
2. Make sure 'show all files' is enabled in solution explorer
3. Select the container file (.xaml not xaml.cs in this case), right-click and include in project. Should be added to the project with the link repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since. The current way in VS 2022 is in `csproj.user`, where you will find items like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="YourControl.xaml.cs">
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
  </Compile>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Page Update="YourControl.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </Page>
```